# How to skip data passing into [NSString stringWithFormat:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, format

Consider below code:

```
int count = 1;
NSString* format = count == 1 ? @"One %2$@" : @"%1$d %2$@s";
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat: format, count, @"Bread"];
```

What `count` is not `1`, the result is valid:

```
2 Breads
4 Breads
```

However the `count` is `1`, then it causes `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"One %2$@", 1, @"Bread"]);
```

Xcode compiler complains with upper code:

```
Data argument not used by format string
```

I know the reason for this error.
However My approach(Dynamic format that may skips some data) is also useful what if it works.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`[NSString stringWithFormat:]` does not support positional parameters.</strike>
That looks like a bug in `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

One workaround (hack) would be to use plain `printf` functions and convert the result to
`NSString`:

```
char *format = count == 1 ? "One %2$s" : "%1$d %2$ss";
char *tmp;
asprintf(&tmp, format, count, "Bread");
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmp];
free(tmp);
```

But the proper solution would be to create a "Localizable.strings" file with 
language plural rules, as described in 
["Handling Noun Plurals and Units of Measurement"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW10)
in the Internationalization and Localization Guide.

See also ["String Localization"](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/string-localization.html)
for documentation and examples.

Comment: "one, many, other" model from Apple is not matches my requirements. 
It is too limited and requires to much things to do at my opinion.

So I decided to create own framework that can handles localization and a plural system that can be mixed with declarative data and programming. And I faced this problem :(

Comment: Oh, and `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` supports positional parameters when it matches number of passing data.

Comment: @jeeeyul: You are right, so it looks like a bug in stringWithFormat. But the workaround works :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace :-

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"One %2$@", 1, @"Bread"]);
```

with Modified below:-

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d,%@",@"One %2$@", 1, @"Bread"]);
```